# Copying Text from Terminal Emacs over SSH?

Tags: terminal-emacs, ssh

I have emacs running on machine A. I then connect to emacs via a terminal (over SSH) from machine B.

**Question:** From Machine B, how do I copy text to Machine B's clipboard to paste it, i.e., into a browser?

Comment: What's your  environment (operating system, desktop manager if applies) and what GUI terminal are you using (xterm, rxvt, gnome-terminal, konsole...)?

Comment: Linux with i3 window manager + gnome terminal.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to execute a command in an emacs session in A to have same text in B's clipboard. For this, you'll probably need to reverse connect somehow and then use something like `xclip` (with the correct `DISPLAY` variable).

Comment: FYI: a related question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41339